# How to handle negative lookbehind in Excel VBA regex?

Tags: excel, regex, vba

The Excel VBA code is using a regular expression to extract section numbers from HTML files. However, the regex includes a negative lookbehind which is not supported in VBA regex. `"(?<!tbl"")>(\d(\.\d)+)<"`

```
Sub GetAllSectionNumbers()
    LRb = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B7:C" & LRb).ClearContents
    Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
    Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    
    fileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    fileDialog.Title = "Select HTML files"
    fileDialog.Filters.Clear
    fileDialog.Filters.Add "HTML files", "*.htm;*.html", 1
    
    If fileDialog.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim file As Variant
    For Each file In fileDialog.SelectedItems
        Dim fileContents As String
        Open file For Input As #1
        fileContents = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
        Close #1
        
        Dim regex As Object
        Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        regex.Pattern = "(?<!tbl"")>(\d(\.\d)+)<"
        regex.Global = True
        regex.IgnoreCase = True
        regex.MultiLine = True
        TRET = regex.Pattern
        filePath = file
        fileFolder = Left(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\"))
        fileNameSource = Mid(filePath, InStrRev(filePath, "\") + 1, 100)
    
        Dim match As Object
        Set match = regex.Execute(fileContents)
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To match.Count - 1
            LRb = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
            Range("B" & LRb).Value = match.Item(i).SubMatches(0)
            Range("C" & LRb).Value = fileNameSource
        Next i
    Next file
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Is there an alternative regex solution for handling this?

Comment: Usually, in these situations, "best regex trick" helps, match what you do not need and match *and capture* what you need. `tbl">\d(?:\.\d)+<|>(\d(?:\.\d)+)<` will work, just only take the captured value (`match.SubMatches(0)`).

Comment: Thank you, that solution worked perfectly. Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are extracting, the traditional approach is to use the "[best regex trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)" that consists in matching what you do not need and matching *and capturing* what you need.

The regex in this specific situation will look like

```
tbl">\d(?:\.\d)+<|>(\d(?:\.\d)+)<
```

In the code, it will look like

```vb
regex.Pattern = "tbl"">\d(?:\.\d)+<|>(\d(?:\.\d)+)<"
```

Next, in your code, you should check if the `match.SubMatches(0)` value is actually present, and if yes, take it since it is what you need.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lj8cwt/1).